# HorizontalAlignment on image not working in PdfPCell in itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am adding a image in PdfPCell and i want that to be center aligned. For that i used following code but its not working

```
            PdfPTable Outertable = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell celltop = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
            iTextSharp.text.Image img10 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"F:\TestPDFGenerator\TestPDFGenerator\TestPDFGenerator\Sumit.JPG");
            img10.ScaleAbsolute(50, 1);
            celltop.AddElement(img10);
            celltop.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            Outertable.AddCell(celltop);
```

please can you tell where i am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the alignment on the image, not the cell:

```
img10.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it helped me a lot. I will surely keep your point in mind and will always accept or will post my own answer and accept that.